# Decimal to octal converter in c

Tags: c

I made a program to convert decimal to octal but it's printing the output in reverse order. Is there maybe a way to store the data that the program is printing so that i can reverse it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter the interger");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int q=n;
    if (n<8)
        printf("%d",n);
    else{
        while(q>=8){
            int r=q%8;
            q=q/8;
            printf("%d",r);

        }
    printf("%d",q);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can put it in an array.

Comment: BTW, you misspelled "integer".

Comment: @Barmar I dont want to use array I haven't learned that yet

Comment: Are you allowed to use `printf()`?

Comment: yes im allowed to use everything I've written in my code. No for loops yet.

Comment: See https://beginnersbook.com/2017/09/c-program-to-convert-decimal-to-octal-number/

Comment: The solution involves creating a decimal number whose digits are the digits from the octal number.

Comment: @Eyyboss in dupe you have my answer converting from decimal to anybase number (base <= 36)

Comment: If you can use printf, you just need `scanf("%d", &n); printf("%o", n);`